# Solving equation that involves the sum of linear terms and the $L_2$ norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}$

I'm trying to solve the following optimization problem:

$$
    \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{2} x^{\mathrm{T}} A x + b^{\mathrm{T}}x + \lVert Cx + d \rVert_2
$$

where $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $d \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

By applying the first order optimality conditions, I obtain that if $\lVert Cx + d \rVert > 0$, then
$$
Ax + b + C^\mathrm{T} \frac{Cx + d}{\lVert Cx + d \rVert_2} = 0
$$
Otherwise, for the case of $\lVert Cx + d \rVert_2 = 0$, by taking the subgradient I obtain
$$
  Ax + b + C^\mathrm{T} g = 0
$$
where $g$ is any vector such that $\lVert g \rVert_2 \leq 1$.

I'm not sure how I should approach solving this problem. In the case where $n=m=1$, assuming that $\lvert Cx + d \rvert > 0$, then
$$
\frac{Cx + d}{ \lVert Cx + d \rVert_2 } = \frac{Cx + d}{ \lvert Cx + d \rvert } = \sign(Cx + d)
$$
Hence,
$$
x = \begin{cases}
    -\frac{b + C}{A} & Cx + d > 0 \\
    -\frac{b - C}{A} & Cx + d < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
and this solution is applicable for $C(-\frac{b+C}{A}) + d > 0$ or $C(-\frac{b-C}{A}) + d < 0$. Otherwise, we apply $Cx + d = 0$ to obtain that $x = -\frac{d}{C}$.
However, I'm not sure how to solve this for the case of $m, n > 1$.
$\endgroup$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If $\lVert Cx + d \rVert = 0$, then we know that $x = C^{-1} d$, otherwise $. However, I'm not sure how to determine whether this is indeed the case or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your minimization problem is best handled in another set of coordinates.  Done right, one can avoid the square roots from the norm term.**

Firstly, your work appears to tacitly assume that $A^{\mathsf{T}}=A$.  I will assume $A$ is symmetric going forward, just for simplicity of notation.  If not, then note that since the transpose is the identity on scalars, when we take the transpose of $x^{\mathsf{T}}Ax$, we obtain $$x^{\mathsf{T}}Ax=x^{\mathsf{T}}A^{\mathsf{T}}x$$  Adding $x^{\mathsf{T}}Ax$ to both sides and dividing by $2$ shows that $$x^{\mathsf{T}}Ax=x^{\mathsf{T}}\left(\frac{A+A^{\mathsf{T}}}{2}\right)x$$  Thus we can replace $A$ by its symmetric part.

**Suppose $C$ is invertible.**  Let $y=Cx+d$, so that $x=C^{-1}y-C^{-1}d$ and let $P=(C^{-1})^{\mathsf{T}}AC^{-1}$.  Note that $P$ is symmetric.  You seek to minimize the expression $$f(y)=\frac{1}{2}y^{\mathsf{T}}Py-\frac{1}{2}y^{\mathsf{T}}Pd-\frac{1}{2}d^{\mathsf{T}}Py+b^{\mathsf{T}}y+\|y\|_2$$ in $y$, where I have dropped the constant terms $\frac{1}{2}d^{\mathsf{T}}Pd$ and $-b^{\mathsf{T}}C^{-1}d$.  Rearranging a little, $$f(y)=\frac{1}{2}y^{\mathsf{T}}Py+\left(b^{\mathsf{T}}-d^{\mathsf{T}}P\right)y+\|y\|_2$$  To avoid writing that monstrosity inside the parentheses, I call it $\phi^{\mathsf{T}}=b^{\mathsf{T}}-d^{\mathsf{T}}P$.

Write $y=au$, where $u$ is a unit vector.  We can now describe our problem as constrained minimization: we want to minimize $$f(au)=\frac{1}{2}a^2u^{\mathsf{T}}Pu+a\phi^{\mathsf{T}}u+a$$  subject to the constraint that $1=u^{\mathsf{T}}u$.

Applying Lagrange multipliers, an extremum occurs when:
\begin{gather*}
au^{\mathsf{T}}Pu+\phi^{\mathsf{T}}u+1=0\quad\quad(\partial_a) \\
a^2(Pu)^{\mathsf{T}}+a\phi^{\mathsf{T}}=2\lambda u^{\mathsf{T}}\quad\quad(\nabla_u) \\
1=u^{\mathsf{T}}u\quad\quad(\text{constraint})
\end{gather*}  Suppose we examine ($\nabla_u$) in the $u$ direction: then $$2\lambda=2\lambda u^{\mathsf{T}}u=a^2u^{\mathsf{T}}Pu+a\phi^{\mathsf{T}}u=-a$$ where the first equality comes from substituting (constraint) and the last from substituting ($\partial_a$).

Eliminating $\lambda$ and canceling a common factor of $a$, we now find $$aPu+\phi=-u$$  This is an eigenvalue problem, which I leave to you.

**If $C$ is not invertible, then we can use the same tricks as above, but the algebra is more complicated.**  I will only sketch these cases.  We can't say that $x=C^{-1}y-C^{-1}d$, but we can say that there is some linear transformation $T$ and (nonlinear!) function $v$ such that $x=Ty-Td+v(y)$  and $v(y)\in\ker{(C)}$ for all $y\in d+\text{im}{(C)}$.  (This follows from the first isomorphism theorem of vector spaces, or, more prosaically, the definitions of image and kernel plus some algebra.)

**To describe how to handle this, I would recommend changing basis to write $C$ as a block matrix: either $C=\begin{bmatrix}I_n&0\end{bmatrix}$ or $C=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_n\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  (Note that this will change your values of $A$ and $b$.)**

**In the former case, where $C$ is surjective,** we can choose a pseudoinverse to make $v$ linear.  Consider $x$ as two separate vectors $(au-d,z)$ adjoined.  Then $Cx+d=au$, and so your problem is to minimize $a+(\text{a polynomial in $a$, $u$, and $z$})$ subject to $1=u^{\mathsf{T}}u$.

**In the latter case, $C$ is only *injective*.  This is the hardest scenario.**  We can write $Cx+d$ as two vectors adjoined, but this does not help us make progress on eliminating the square roots.  Instead, I would interpret your optimization problem as a *highly-constrained* one.  To wit, let $\pi_1=\begin{bmatrix}I_n&0\end{bmatrix}$ be the projection $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\pi_2$ the complementary projection, so that $\pi_1C=I_n$ and $\pi_2C=0$.  Then you want to minimize $$a^2u^{\mathsf{T}}\pi_1^{\mathsf{T}}A\pi_1u+ab^{\mathsf{T}}\pi_1u+a$$ subject to the constraints $a\pi_2u=\pi_2d$ and $1=u^{\mathsf{T}}u$.  (Note that this requires $m-n+1$ many Lagrange multipliers!)

Comment: I think there's a typo when you substitute $x$ for $y$ that doesn't change the correctness of your answer.

$b^{\mathrm{T}} x = b^{\mathrm{T}} \Big(C^{-1} y - C^{-1} d \Big)$, but you've got $b^{\mathrm{T}} x = b^{\mathrm{T}} y$ written in your answer.

Comment: Also, in the case that $C^{-1}$ is invertible, you say that the equation $aPu + \phi = -u$ is an eigenvalue problem. However, isn't this only the case when $\phi = 0$? If $\phi$ is nonzero, then how would you solve this?

Comment: @oswinso: Yes, if $\phi\neq0$, then only the homogenous part is an eigenvalue problem.  If $a^{-1}$ isn't an eigenvalue of $P$, then $-\phi=(aP+I_n)u$, which uniquely determines $u$ (and likely isn't a unit vector).  For the other (finitely-many) $a$, the same formula _plus any element of the corresponding eigenspace_ will be a satisfactory $u$...so find all eigenvectors that make the sum a unit vector.

Comment: Also, typo now fixed.