# Eigenvalue-like equation with additional constant term

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4069061/solving-equation-that-involves-the-sum-of-linear-terms-and-the-l-2-norm), the answer states that the solution (changing the notation to be consistent with Linear Algebra)
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda} A \vec{v} + \vec{b} = \vec{v}
$$
where the unknowns are $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lVert \vec{v} \rVert = 1$.
The solution states that the above is an **eigenvalue problem**. However, to the best of my understanding, this is only the case when $\vec{b} = \vec{0}$.

How does one solve an equation of the above form when $\vec{b} \not = \vec{0}$?

Comment: It's a non-homogeneous linear system parameterized by $\lambda$.

Comment: Sure. How would you solve this though?
Since both $\lambda$ and $\vec{v}$ are unknown, there are $n+1$ unknowns, and I need to make use of the constraint $\lVert \vec{v} \rVert = 1$ in order to solve for $\lambda$ and $\vec{v}$. I'm not sure how you would do that though.

Comment: In an eigenvalue problem, one is not interested in having $v=0$ as the sole solution, which is why one forces the matrix to be singular. Try the same here. You should get affine spaces, rather than vector (eigen)spaces. It would be easier to comment if you mentioned where this problem comes from.

Comment: I'm still don't think I fully understand what you mean. I can reorganize terms to obtain that
$(\frac{1}{\lambda} A - I) \vec{v} = -\vec{b}$. Via the normal eigenvalue problem, I can find a $\lambda$ such that $\frac{1}{\lambda} A - I$ is singular. I'm not sure what I would do after that to find $\vec{v}$ though.

This problem comes from the question that I've linked in this question, where I'm trying to (basically) optimize the sum of a quadratic and $\ell_2$ norm of the decision variable.

Comment: Have you tried Gaussian elimination? Pick a small matrix $A$. Gain intuition from small toy examples before aiming at the general $n$.